# Datamapper Codeigniter use condition in where_related clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-datamapper

**Table Structure**

```
I have three Database tables as :
1.)  Deal_Team
     id, deal_id, title, status, insert_time
2.) Deal_Team_User
     id, deal_team_id, user_id, status, insert_time
3.) Attachment_To_Deal_Team
    id, attachment_id, deal_team_id, insert_time
```

**PHP Code is as follows:**

```
$objDealTeam = new Deal_Team();
$objDealTeam->where_related('deal_team_user', 'user_id', $user_id);
$objDealTeam->where_related('attachment_to_deal_team' , 'id >=' ,'0' );
echo $objDealTeam->get_sql(NULL,NULL,TRUE);die;
```

**Built Query for above code :**

SELECT `depl_deal_team`.* FROM (`depl_deal_team`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `depl_deal_team_user` depl_deal_team_user ON `depl_deal_team`.`id` = `depl_deal_team_user`.`deal_team_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `depl_attachment_to_deal_teams` depl_attachment_to_deal_teams ON `depl_deal_team`.`id` = `depl_attachment_to_deal_teams`.`deal_team_id` WHERE

> `depl_deal_team_user`.`user_id` = '10' AND
>   `depl_attachment_to_deal_teams`.`id` = '0'

**Desired Query:**

SELECT `depl_deal_team`.* FROM (`depl_deal_team`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `depl_deal_team_user` depl_deal_team_user ON `depl_deal_team`.`id` = `depl_deal_team_user`.`deal_team_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `depl_attachment_to_deal_teams` depl_attachment_to_deal_teams ON `depl_deal_team`.`id` = `depl_attachment_to_deal_teams`.`deal_team_id` WHERE

> `depl_deal_team_user`.`user_id` = '10' AND
>   `depl_attachment_to_deal_teams`.`id` >= '0'

**Thanks In Advance**